# Angular expression in ng-repeat and ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a function using `ng-click` which is dynamically generated by `ng-repeat` the problem is that i am not able to get the parameter value passed in `ng-click` function. My html code is

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in uploadedFiles">
    <b>value.filename is {{value.filename}}</b>
    <img ng-if="value.filetype=='jpg'" ng-src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/{{value.filename}}" class="img img-responsive thumbnail uploadedfile-thumb"/>
    <img ng-if="value.filetype=='PDF'" ng-src="images/pdf-thumb.jpg" class="img img-responsive thumbnail uploadedfile-thumb"/>
    <a ng-href="http://localhost:3000/uploads/{{value.filename}}" target="_blank" class="uploaded-file-links">View</a>
    <a ng-href="#" ng-click="deleteFile(value.filename);" class="uploaded-file-links">Delete</a>
</div>
```

i am not getting the filename which is passed in `deleteFile()`, bit it is working in `<b>` tag in 2nd line so finally this is a problem with my angular expression so how should i write it?

Comment: Put alert or console.log in your deleteFile and see what you're getting?

Comment: Now it's working, Thank you.

Comment: it would be nice if you post your solution so other people will know what was the problem ;)

Comment: The HTML code is fine the mistake was in alert(); i was using comma(,) as a concatenation operator instead of plus(+) .

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make some guessing here.

I suppose that your `uploadedFiles` is an array of objecs, and not an object itself. In that case, you should use `ng-repeat="file in uploadedFiles"` which is meant to iterate over array elements. This will iterate over your array and assignf the corresponding object for that iteration to `file` variable.

The `ng-repeat="(key, value) in uploadedFiles"` is meant for iterating over object properties instead of iterating over array elements. For example, if `uploadedFiles` is:

```
var uploadedFiles = {
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: 'value3'
};
```

and you iterate over it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in uploadedFiles">
        {{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

you would get the following output:

- value1
- value2
- value3

But if `uploadedFiles` is an array like this one:

```
var uploadedFiles = [
    {
        prop1: 'value11',
        prop2: 'value12',
    },
    {
        prop1: 'value21',
        prop2: 'value22',
    },
    {
        prop1: 'value31',
        prop2: 'value32',
    }
];
```

And you iterate over it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="file in uploadedFiles">
        {{file.prop1}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

you would get:

- value11
- value21
- value31

So in your case, I would try the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="file in uploadedFiles">
    <b>file.filename is {{file.filename}}</b>
    <img ng-if="file.filetype=='jpg'" ng-src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/{{file.filename}}" class="img img-responsive thumbnail uploadedfile-thumb"/>
    <img ng-if="file.filetype=='PDF'" ng-src="images/pdf-thumb.jpg" class="img img-responsive thumbnail uploadedfile-thumb"/>
    <a ng-href="http://localhost:3000/uploads/{{file.filename}}" target="_blank" class="uploaded-file-links">View</a>
    <a ng-href="#" ng-click="deleteFile(file.filename);" class="uploaded-file-links">Delete</a>
</div>
```